# How to block user in buddypress so user can not send mail

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have installed buddypress, BP Profile Message UX Free, bbPress,bbPress Moderation plugins for a web site.  My problem area is  when a user try to block another user for private and public messaging, where/how can i implement this.

I have seen a plugin named buddyblock which can restrict user to message each other but this plugin is not free. I am looking for something free or looking for code.

I have found alternative of buddyblock in a blog : 
https://buddypress.org/support/topic/modemloopers-solution-to-buddyblock-alternative/ . 
In this blog i found a link of code :
https://gist.github.com/modemlooper/6a79a602e322ad5d9bbf09893da9cdea
But i do not know, how I can use the code. Where to put user-settings.php?
Can any one give me any solution which can ensure user from unwanted email and user can block and unblock specific user from messaging.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you read through the post that you mention: https://buddypress.org/support/topic/modemloopers-solution-to-buddyblock-alternative/. 
As it says in the last answer, you should put the code in your bp-custom.php file. The bp-custom.php file does not exist by default, you'll have to create it if you haven't done so already. It's quite simple, here you can see how to do it: https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/bp-custom-php/. Most custom code that you'll want to use with BuddyPress goes to this file.
Once you create it, copy modemlooper's code, paste it in the bp-custom.php file and test it out. I haven't used the code myself, so I can't say if and how well it works. Usually it is a good idea to make a backup before trying any modifications.

Hope that helps